# Angular 2 child router doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

My project structure is like this:

> Login -> Dashboard -> Home

Home is the child of the Dashboard.

What I want is to redirect to **Login** Page when user not logged in. The guard class is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

@Injectable()
export class CanActivateGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor() {}

  canActivate() {
    return Meteor.userId() != null;
  }
}
```

Module for Dashboard:

```
import { CanActivateGuard } from '../activate-guard';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    CanActivateGuard
  ],
```

Router for Dashboard:

```
import { CanActivateGuard } from '../activate-guard';

export const DASHBOARD_ROUTES: Route[] = [
  { 
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [CanActivateGuard],
    children: [
      ...HOME_ROUTES
    ]
```

Module for home:

```
import { CanActivateGuard } from '../../activate-guard';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
        CanActivateGuard
  ],
```

Router for home:

```
import { CanActivateGuard } from '../../activate-guard';

export const HOME_ROUTES : Route[] = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [CanActivateGuard] }
]
```

This is working fine if my url is: http://localhost:3000/dashboard, it will redirect to login page. But it will become blank screen if the url is: http://localhost:3000/dashboard/home.

I really don't understand what happened. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i  definen route something like this in a single routing file.ts which is working fine for me
const appRoutes: Routes = [
 {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/LogIn',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
   {
        path: 'LogIn',
        component: LoginComponent
    },

```
{
    path: 'DashBoard',
    component: DashboardComponent ,
    children: [
        { path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
        { path: 'Home', component: HomeComponent},



    ]
},
```